# Split comma separated values inside column and count values that satisfy criteria, with mysql

Tags: mysql

This is a tough problem. I have some comma separated timestamps inside a column field, ex. timestamps_field contains:
            1432746869,1432746869,1432746871,1432746871

I needed the count of the timestamps older than one day, something like this:

SELECT **Count_older_timestamps**(timestamps_field) as older_count_timestamps FROM Table

**Count_older_timestamps** should be a stored procedure? Does it exist some buildin function or a combination of functions that would resolve this problem?

Comment: well the built in function is to normalize properly, then use simple SQL.

Comment: sorry but I don't undestand you suggestion

Answer (score 0):

you need to fix the normalization.

create a new table similar to this:

```
event_times
--------------
myothertable_id
timestamp
event_description
```

then parse out all the comma separated stuff and insert rows here.

then write simple SQL.